# I downloaded a photo from internet and after cutting the part i don't want in Photoshop it got blurred

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, photo-editing, image-quality, photography

I downloaded a photo from internet and after cutting the part i don't want in Photoshop it got blurred. I am a beginner in Photoshop and i don't know how to make it in the best quality or at least in the same quality as i downloaded.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, but there's quite many possible reasons why something  gets blurred or looks out like just blurred, altough it was blurred all the time or is actually sharp but looks out blurred because the subject is blurry. You should show just your case as screenshots and with an explanation what you did.

Comment: I think the better question is what are you trying to do with cut-out part? Are you setting up a print file or what medium will your final file be output to? Images off the internet tend to be at 72dpi. If it's a large image, you would probably be opening it in photoshop at around 33% where it may look sharp on your screen. If you're cropping out a small part of the image (or cutting and pasting a small part into a new document), it may then view at 100%. At 100% it will then look blurry/pixelated.

Answer (score 0):

Most Internet images are low resolution or slightly blurry, or both. At small scaling, it is not too noticeable. Also the image could have jpeg artifacts which could be partially corrected.
First step is to look for a higher quality version of the image you want to work with. Then bring that image into Photoshop. Use Image Size_Resample_Enlarge to double or quadruple the pixel dimensions. Then Save As_tif or psd for your working copy. Later you can make a jpeg or whatever you need for output.
Zoom into the area you plan to crop and look for any faults. You may choose to sharpen. I use the Layer_Copy, High_Pass_Filter, Soft_Light_Blend method. You can also use the Clone Stamp to cover edge bubbles and other artifacts. Save this image, then crop and save as. You will keep the full image if you need to change the crop dimensions later.